# Failed building wheel for PySide when installing pyside on Mac

Tags: pyside

I have installed:

*Python 3.6.1
*qt/5.9.1

*sip-4.19.3

When I type

```
pip install pyside
```

Or

```
pip install -U PySide
```

I always get the error bellow:

```
Collecting PySide
  Using cached PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: PySide
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PySide ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/tv/4rb2txws5ml_cwj0v060ym_80000gn/T/pip-build-jscv9F/PySide/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/tv/4rb2txws5ml_cwj0v060ym_80000gn/T/tmp5VfNR7pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  Removing /private/var/folders/tv/4rb2txws5ml_cwj0v060ym_80000gn/T/pip-build-jscv9F/PySide/pyside_package
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Python architecture is 64bit
  error: Failed to find qmake. Please specify the path to qmake with --qmake parameter.

  ----------------------------------------
```

> Failed building wheel for PySide

```
Running setup.py clean for PySide
Failed to build PySide
Installing collected packages: PySide
  Running setup.py install for PySide ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/tv/4rb2txws5ml_cwj0v060ym_80000gn/T/pip-build-jscv9F/PySide/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/tv/4rb2txws5ml_cwj0v060ym_80000gn/T/pip-lTCccK-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Removing /private/var/folders/tv/4rb2txws5ml_cwj0v060ym_80000gn/T/pip-build-jscv9F/PySide/pyside_package
    running install
    running build
    Python architecture is 64bit
    error: Failed to find qmake. Please specify the path to qmake with --qmake parameter.

    ----------------------------------------

Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/tv/4rb2txws5ml_cwj0v060ym_80000gn/T/pip-build-jscv9F/PySide/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n','\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record /var/folders/tv/4rb2txws5ml_cwj0v060ym_80000gn/T/pip-lTCccK-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
/private/var/folders/tv/4rb2txws5ml_cwj0v060ym_80000gn/T/pip-build-jscv9F/PySide/
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I finally found a "solution".

First of all, I am not an expert (I am super new coding).
Based on my own experience below you will find a solution as well.

I need to clarify something first, there are two ways to use this GUI QT - PyQt by Riverbank Computing or(and) PySide, originally developed by Nokia.

I tried many differents ways to install PySide, but no success, so I ended up finding PyQt, that does the same thing.

Watching this video I installed the PyQT5 in my Mac OS and now it is working.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kHk8ZjxH64

Example of Hello World using PyQT
http://pythoncentral.io/intro-to-pysidepyqt-basic-widgets-and-hello-world/

The wiki.qt.io says
"PySide has included support for Python 3.2 since version 1.0.8." but it doesn't work for me.

Good lucky.

Comment: I faced a similar problem when trying to run git-cola. It was failing because of PySide. After I installed PyQt5 and PyQt4, it started working correctly. Thank you.